# Sql Select From multiple table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

```
Visitor table
VisitorId (pk)
Name
Phone


Country table
CountryId (pk)
Name
Code

Travels table
TravelId (pk)
CountryId (fk)
VisitorId (fk)
IsVisited (bool)
```

I want to able that foreach country to create another entrace in `Travels` table that will contains `CountryId`, `VisitorId` and `false` for `IsVisited`.

**UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO Travels (CountryId, VisitorID, IsVisisted)
SELECT Visitor.VisitorId, Country.CountryId, 1 FROM Visitor, Country
```

Comment: please include your query so far and tell us where you're stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write as:

```
-- STEP2: Insert records:
INSERT INTO @Travels 
SELECT CountryId,VisitorId,0 FROM -- 0 = false for IsVisited
(
-- STEP1: first create a combination for all visitor Id and country Id 
-- and get all the combinations which are not there in existing Travels table
SELECT C.CountryId,V.VisitorId
FROM @Country C
CROSS JOIN @Visitor V
EXCEPT
SELECT CountryId,VisitorId
FROM @Travels
) AS T
```

else if you want to create an entry for each combination in `Country` and `Visitor` write as:

```
-- STEP2: Insert records:
INSERT INTO @Travels 
SELECT  CountryId,VisitorId,0 FROM 
(
-- STEP1: first create a combination for all visitor Id and country Id 
SELECT C.CountryId,V.VisitorId
FROM @Country C
CROSS JOIN @Visitor V
) AS T

SELECT * FROM @Travels
```